# Is there a way so simplify this with less code?

Tags: c#

Is there a more efficient a way to do this calculation?

Term1 is the first term (which is added on in the beginning of the calculation).
numberOfTs is the number that each previous calculation is multiplied by.
AOS is addition or subtraction, this is the last number to be plugged into the calculation.

```
Console.WriteLine ("Tn+1 = ({0})Tn +/- ({1})", numberOfTs, AOS);
Console.Write ("{0}", term1);
int calc1 = term1 * numberOfTs + AOS;   
Console.Write (", {0}", calc1);             
int calc2 = calc1 * numberOfTs + AOS;
Console.Write (", {0}", calc2);
int calc3 = calc2 * numberOfTs + AOS;  
Console.Write (", {0}", calc3);
int calc4 = calc3 * numberOfTs + AOS;
Console.Write (", {0}", calc4);
int calc5 = calc4 * numberOfTs + AOS;
Console.Write (", {0}", calc5);
int calc6 = calc5 * numberOfTs + AOS;
Console.Write (", {0}", calc6);
```

Comment: Just use a loop?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple for-loop and storing the previous calculation. This would make your code better, not even shorter. Because if you want to change some thing, you only have to do it once.

```
Console.WriteLine ("Tn+1 = ({0})Tn +/- ({1})", numberOfTs, AOS);
Console.Write ("{0}", term1);
int calc = term1;

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    calc = calc * numberOfTs + AOS;   
    Console.Write (", {0}", calc);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple `for` loop will do:

```
int previous = term1;

Console.WriteLine($"Tn+1 = ({numberOfTs})Tn +/- ({AOS})");
Console.Write(previous);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     previous = previous * numberOfTs + AOS;   
     Console.Write($", {previous}");
}
```

Comment: This will only work with the newest version of c# ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cycle, basic cycle to all programming languages are:

- for
- while

Take a look at them man.

```
calc = term1;
for(i=0; i<6;i++){
   int calc = calc * numberOfTs + AOS;   
   Console.Write (", {0}", calc);  
}
```